# Terraform Variable $input of type CreateBranchProtectionRuleInput! was provided invalid value for blocksCreations

Tags: github, terraform

I'm trying to do a simple github branch protection rule through terraform with the following resource definition:

```
resource "github_branch_protection" "branch" {
  repository_id  = github_repository.repo["test3"].id
  pattern        = "master"
  allows_deletions = false
}
```

Nothing fancy in there at all. However, I get this error when trying to apply it:

```
│ Error: Variable $input of type CreateBranchProtectionRuleInput! was provided invalid value for blocksCreations (Field is not defined on CreateBranchProtectionRuleInput), bypassPullRequestActorIds (Field is not defined on CreateBranchProtectionRuleInput), requireLastPushApproval (Field is not defined on CreateBranchProtectionRuleInput), lockBranch (Field is not defined on CreateBranchProtectionRuleInput)
```

Here's some environment info for reference:

```
provider "github" {
  owner    = "fakecompany"
  base_url = "https://github.fakecompany.com"
}

terraform {
  backend "gcs" {
    bucket = "fakename-tf-state"
    prefix = "state/my-test"
  }
  required_providers {
    github = {
      source  = "integrations/github"
      version = "~> 5.26.0"
    }
  }
}

terraform version
Terraform v1.4.6
on linux_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/integrations/github v5.26.0
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to get around this error? I feel like I must be missing something obvious.

Thanks!

Comment: This appears to be an error sourced from `go-github` if anything, but speculating a bit there. Since your usage appears to be completely compliant with the resource documentation, then you probably need to raise an issue on the provider and/or SDK (but provider first).